# Ghostscript + QPDF and PDF/A-1b validation: how to add EOL separator before endstreams

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to define an up to date method for converting any PDF into a PDF/A-1b able to pass [3-Heights](https://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx) validation. I came up with this script which uses ghostscript and [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net):

```
#! /bin/bash
# transforms input PDF into an optimized PDF/A-1b
# usage: $0 input.pdf output.pdf

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dPrinted=true -dPDFA -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -dDetectDuplicateImages -r150 -sOutputFile=$2 $1  
qpdf --linearize $2 $2.optimized
mv $2.optimized $2
```

Which transforms any PDF into a web optimized PDF/A-1b.

Everything is good, except that ghostscript seems not to add missing EOLs before endstreams, which won't allow the processed document to pass the validation. This is the validation result I get:

```
Validating file "document.pdf" for conformance level pdfa-1b
  The separator before 'endstream' must be an EOL. (5)
  The document does not conform to the requested standard.
The file format (header, trailer, objects, xref, streams) is corrupted.
Done.
```

Do you know any way or tool with which these EOL separators can be added?

Valid and up to date alternative suggestions to convert PDF to PDF/A-1b are welcome too.

Comment: I think your problem may be more with `qpdf`; see also https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues/38 from 2014.  Not sure if this ever got fixed.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, you're right: the problem is `qpdf`! The issue is still not fixed then, as I'm able to reproduce it with the script above.

I gave another look at ghostscript, and found out it was already capable of linearizing PDFs. I'll *self-answer* to show how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was blindly focused on `ghostscript`, but thanks to Stephen, I found out it seems due to a bug in `qpdf`. I'll submit a clear report via GitHub.

We can do all the work with `ghostscript` alone, since from version 9.07 it can linearize PDFs with a simple additional flag, as reported also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8390572).

I want to complete my answer not only providing an up to date method to convert a PDF into the A-1b format with `ghostscript`, but also reporting how to validate it locally with `java` and preflight tool from Apache PDFBox library.

## Converting any PDF to PDF/A-1b with Ghostscript 9.19

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dPrinted=true -dPDFA -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -dDetectDuplicateImages -r150 -dFastWebView=true -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

---

## Validating your PDF/A-1b locally with Java 8 and Apache PDFBox preflight

All the infos in the code comments. Download latest `preflight-app` from [Apache PDFBox site](https://pdfbox.apache.org).

At the time of writing, latest version is 2.0.2.

```
/**
 * Source:
 * https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/pdfavalidation.html
 *
 * Compilation:
 * $ javac -cp preflight-app.2.0.2.jar:. Validator.java
 *
 * Usage:
 * $ java -cp preflight-app.2.0.2.jar:. Validator input.pdf
 */

import org.apache.pdfbox.preflight.ValidationResult;
import org.apache.pdfbox.preflight.parser.PreflightParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.preflight.PreflightDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.preflight.exception.SyntaxValidationException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.preflight.ValidationResult.ValidationError;

public class Validator {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        ValidationResult result = null;
        PreflightParser parser = new PreflightParser(args[0]);

        try {
            parser.parse();
            PreflightDocument document = parser.getPreflightDocument();
            document.validate();
            result = document.getResult();
            document.close();
        } catch (SyntaxValidationException e) {
            result = e.getResult();
        }

        if( result.isValid() )
            System.out.println("The file " + args[0] + " is a valid PDF/A-1b file");
        else {
            System.out.println("The file " + args[0] + " is not valid, error(s) :");
            for( ValidationError error : result.getErrorsList() )
                System.out.println(error.getErrorCode() + " : " + error.getDetails());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to successfully make a PDF A-1b complient with that `gs` command. When I check the result apache pdfbox preflight, I get `2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, DestOutputProfile is missing` and similarly the validator at https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx complains `A device-specific color space (DeviceRGB) without an appropriate output intent is used.`

Comment: That command is quite old, try with this one: https://github.com/lcpz/dots/blob/master/bin/compresspdf

Comment: Still no luck. Did it really work for you? Even with `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor    -dCompressFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dPDFA -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dFastWebView=true -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf` the result will not have icc profile data embedded and is thus not pdf/a-1b compliant. What did help was to add `/usr/share/ghostscript/9.27/lib/PDFA_def.ps` (on Debian) as an additional input. That file adds `srgb.icc` from `/usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/` to the result.